# POCO Linking error, undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 on OS X 10.11.2

Tags: c++, linker, g++, clang, poco-libraries

I installed POCO using Homebrew.
Someone suggested using stdlibc++ instead, but when I do that, I get a bunch of std linking errors in addition to the POCO linking errors.
I also tried using g++ from Homebrew's gcc instead of Apple's g++, but that gives the same errors.

**Makefile**

```
CXX=g++
RM=rm -f
CXXFLAGS=-std=c++11 -Wall -O3 -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/poco/1.6.1/include
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/poco/1.6.1/lib
LDLIBS=-lPocoNet -lPocoFoundation

SRCS=eml.cc
OBJS=$(subst .cc,.o,$(SRCS))

all: eml

eml: $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o eml $(OBJS) $(LDLIBS)

%.o: %.c
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    $(RM) eml $(OBJS)
```

**Errors**

```
g++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -Wall -O3 -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/poco/1.6.1/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/poco/1.6.1/lib -o eml eml.o -lPocoNet -lPocoFoundation -lcrypto
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Poco::Net::SSLManager::initializeClient(Poco::SharedPtr<Poco::Net::PrivateKeyPassphraseHandler, Poco::ReferenceCounter, Poco::ReleasePolicy<Poco::Net::PrivateKeyPassphraseHandler> >, Poco::SharedPtr<Poco::Net::InvalidCertificateHandler, Poco::ReferenceCounter, Poco::ReleasePolicy<Poco::Net::InvalidCertificateHandler> >, Poco::AutoPtr<Poco::Net::Context>)", referenced from:
      _main in eml.o
  "Poco::Net::SSLManager::instance()", referenced from:
      _main in eml.o
  "Poco::Net::initializeSSL()", referenced from:
      _main in eml.o
  "Poco::Net::uninitializeSSL()", referenced from:
      _main in eml.o
  "Poco::Net::SecureStreamSocket::SecureStreamSocket(Poco::Net::SocketAddress const&)", referenced from:
      _main in eml.o
  "Poco::Net::SecureStreamSocket::~SecureStreamSocket()", referenced from:
      _main in eml.o
  "Poco::Net::AcceptCertificateHandler::AcceptCertificateHandler(bool)", referenced from:
      _main in eml.o
  "Poco::Net::Context::Context(Poco::Net::Context::Usage, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, Poco::Net::Context::VerificationMode, int, bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      _main in eml.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [eml] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not linking all the required libraries. All of the unresolved
symbols are defined in `libPocoNetSSL`. To install this library you must build the
full version, not the basic version version, of the POCO libraries.

If you consult the documentation of any of the POCO APIs it will tell you the libraries you need to link,
e.g. [`Poco::Net::SSLManager::initializeClient`](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Net.SSLManager.html).